# How do I convert scheduled recurring entries into clocked data?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I use org-mode for scheduling and logging in tasks. I clock in non-recurring tasks, however I find it strenuous to clock in recurring tasks. Is there any way I can mark the recurring task done and the scheduled time for the task is converted into clocked data as soon as I mark it done?

Example,

```
* TODO Task 1
SCHEDULED: <2016-10-04 Tue 10:00-10:30 ++1d>
```

After I mark it done, the task should read

```
* TODO Task 1
SCHEDULED: <2016-10-05 Wed 10:00-10:30>
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2016-10-04 Tue 11:42]
CLOCK: [2016-10-04 Tue 10:00]--[2016-10-04 Tue 10:30] => 0:30
:END:
```

Comment: Since you don't seem to clock a start time or an end time where is it getting the effort from?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fully answers your question. You can log state changes. For example, take a note and log a time when changing from WAITING to TODO etc.

https://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html